# Width is Stretching out more than it should

Tags: html, css

I have this website: http://www.deguaraconfectionery.com/ and if you scroll to the right you can see there is some extra space on the right. Not sure why this happened.

The image attached shows how the site looks when scrolled to the right. The site looks great on default view, but am hating this extra space on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

your addThis box is the culprit

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; top: 50px; left: 720px;">
```

That is too wide @600px and is overflowing to the right.. as it's style is being set inline you need to adjust that down a bit - I think about 200-250px should do it

Comment: Thanks, I had made that to test, forgot about it :/ Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the buttons for share this with a width of 600px, you should check that.

Answer (score 1):

Your shareThis link container is set to 600px and pushing the edge to the right, I deleted it from the DOM and the page looks fine (FF4). This did come as a surprise to me though since it is `position:absolute`, still you should look at `right:0` instead of `left:750px`, and then align the links to the right.

I think you need to invest some time in learning how to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

That's how I answered your last question in 0.3 seconds :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and suggestion, I have firebug, need to learn to debug with it more.

Answer (score 1):

I found following line is causing the problem

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 600px; top: 50px; left: 700px;" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
```

I changed the the `width` to `200px` and it worked fine